# Jsp showing error

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse-mars

I am getting the error in my eclipse mars. It won't show any pop up for that these errors. And I am able to successfully run even after the errors, though in this particular case that that is also a issue.

1. I had to run my server again and again, it's not picking up changes.
2. Why these red squiggly line.
3. I am getting below error when trying to run this.

   [image: Why red flags]

Error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 13 in the jsp file: /HelloWorld.jsp
Date cannot be resolved to a type
10: 
11: <%
12: 
13: Date today = new java.util.Date();
14: 
15: String text = "Today's date is: " + today.toString();
16: %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import date-class or fully qualify both.

Either put this at the top of your page:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
....
Date today = new Date();
```

or:

```
java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't import Date class in your JSP page :
Place following code at the top place of jsp page.

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your missing an import. Without that import Java/JSP "don't know" Date. There are to ways to deal with this error:

1.- Import Date on the top of your page, to tell your programm "where to find Date":

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
```

2.- Or you could easily tell him it right in the line where you declaring the variable:

```
java.util.Date yourDate= new java.util.Date();
```

Note that if your using the second way it won't work for other variables than `yourDate`.